# How do I return the x position of an object of 2D shapes without using fixed numbers?

Tags: java

I have a 2D rocket, the rocket is a collection of 3 objects, a nose(triangle), body(square) and a jet(circle), all together they make the rocket.

I have to set the body(square) relative to the nose(triangle), so that they align with each other.

So far I have this;

```
public Rocket(Triangle t, Square s, Circle c) {
  this.nose = t;
  this.body = s; 
  this.jet = c;    
  this.nose.setXPos(50);//initial positions of the nose X
  this.nose.setYPos(300);//initial positions of the nose Y
  this.body.setXPos(getBodyXPos());//sets the body relative to the nose X
  this.body.setYPos(getBodyYPos());//sets the body relative to the nose Y
```

I also have the methods;

```
private int getBodyXPos()
   {   
   return this.xPos;
}

private int getBodyYPos()
{
  return this.yPos;
}

private int getJetXPos()
{
   return this.xPos;
}

private int getJetYPos()
{
  return this.yPos;
}
```

I am not aloud to use fixed number, but need to use the helper method in some way to make the shapes appear in the correct place on the screen.
I have been stuck on this for a few days and would love some help.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems that you need to define first how the shapes need to be drawn with regard to each other.  Then, it is not clear what type of triangle you have: equilateral, isosceles, or scalene; which point of a triangle is represented with `xPos, yPos` - any vertex, some specific vertex, barycenter, incenter etc.  So generally it's up to you to do this homework which is more about geometry.

Answer (score 0):

you simply set the position of the various parts relative to each other with the appropriate offset

```
int rocketx = 50;
int rockety = 300;
this.nose.setXPos(rocketx);
this.nose.setYPos(rockeyy);
this.body.setXPos(rocketx);
this.body.setYPos(rockety+this.nose.height()); 
this.jet.setXPos(rocketx);
this.jet.setYPos(rockety+this.nose.height()+this.body.height());
```

instead of fixed values for height, you might have a method on nose and body to find out their height, and use that instead.  If your rocket is flying horizontal, then you will need to do the same for X and NOT for Y.

Comment: There are methods in the triangle, square and circle objects such as length and width, but I can not work out which ones to use and how to use them in the rocket object code.  Everything I've tried either has not complied or not moved the square and circle to where it needs to be.

Comment: Get a piece of graph paper.  Mark it for appropriately scaled dimensions, draw the triangle and then label all the various measures, like height and width.   Draw the other shapes and label them.   You still have not clarified if you want it horizontal or vertical, but figure that out.  Then see which values add to be the position of the object.  The calculation is just addition, you just need to find the right things to add.

Comment: There are methods in the subclasses Triangle, square and circle of this.getHeight for triangle, this.getLength for square and this.getDiameter for circle, unfortunately I can not work out how to write them into the code for rocket.